# Calling a Javascript class method gets error 'Can't find variable'

Tags: javascript, jasmine, es6-class, teaspoon

When I run my teaspoon-jasmine test, I get the following error.

#### Error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: modify_create_favorite in
>   http://localhost:3000/assets/favorite.self-67fd17843e64bfbeed401bd.js?body=1?body=1
>   (line 49)

#### favorite.js file

```
class Favorites {

  static create(listing_id) {
    modify_create_favorite(find_favorite(listing_id));
  }

  static find_favorite(listing_id) {
    return $("#i-favorite-"+listing_id);
  }

  static modify_create_favorite(object) {
    object.removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart').parent().attr('data-method','delete');
  }
}
```

#### teaspoon jasmine:

```
  it("will change the class", function() {
    fixture.set(favorite_html);
    Favorites.create('17');
    expect( $('#i-favorite-17', fixture.el) ).not.toHaveClass( 'fa-heart-o')
    expect( $('#i-favorite-17', fixture.el) ).toHaveClass( 'fa-heart')
    expect( $('#i-favorite-17', fixture.el).parent() ).toHaveAttr("data-method",'delete')    
    expect(jQuery).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: `this.modify_create_favorite(find_favorite(listing_id));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` methods can only be invoked by calling the class without creating an instance, so inside `create` you should do:

```
Favorites.modify_create_favorite(Favorite.find_favorite(listing_id))

//or 
this.modify_create_favorite(this.find_favorite(listing_id))
```

In your current implementation your code is looking for a function called `modify_create_favorite()` because doesn't know that is a method of your class.

More on `static` methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/reference/Classes/static

Comment: *In order to call a static method within another static method of the same class, you can use the `this` keyword.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/reference/Classes/static#From_another_static_method

Comment: woops my life has been a lie, thank you @connexo! Editing answer